# Extract number of edge pixels in pycharm - opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

Hy,

I want to extract the contour of a mole from a skin image and after that to calculate the number of edge pixels but i don't know how to eliminate the small contours from the big one. I think the problem is at the thresholding.
Can somebody help me?
Thx for help!

I attached an example of image and my code:

[image]

```
grayscaled = cv2.cvtColor(Original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(grayscaled, 150,225, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
filter = cv2.Canny(threshold,100,200)
cv2.imshow('Filter', filter)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: try blurring the image before finding edges

Comment: If you are actually interested in the length of the perimeter, rather than the number of pixels, see here: [Measuring boundary length](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/310). The pixel count underestimates the perimeter.

Comment: ok, I will try. thx

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Convert to Gray, or extract some channel in some Color-Space(HSV or so)
> 2. Threshold to binary, morphologyEx to remove noise
> 3. Find the max contour

[image]

[image]

[image]